# Illustrator file saved as .jpeg file color look completely wrong online. Why?

Tags: website-design, color-conversion, color-profile

So, I saved an Illustrator file as a .jpeg file and it looked completely wrong online. I went back and realized the color mode was CMYK, so I figured it should be in RGB for web. I tried to change the color mode to RGB, but then the image disappeared completely. What's going on? The file was created in CS5 originally but I opened it and saved it in CS6, not sure if that would affect anything.

Thanks,
Amelia

Comment: The artwork in the Illustrator file disappeared when you switched colour modes? That doesn't sound normal. Could you post a screenshot of the artwork so we can see what you're working with?

Answer (score -2):

Save the file as '**Save for Web**', and then choose **.jpeg fie** type with 100% Quality. It won't display any error and you will get a High Quality Image.